# Gstream ARM cross compilation

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, gstreamer

I want to write an embedded GStreamer application for an ARM processor. I have a Freescale enviroment,which contains installed gstream-0.10 & cross-compiler toolchain.
I took a first Hello World application from GStream manual and tried to compile it by

> arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc video_1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`

My gstreamer-0.10.pc consists:

```
prefix=/home/.../build_mx6q/tmp/sysroots/varsommx6q/usr
exec_prefix=/usr
libdir=/home/.../build_mx6q/tmp/sysroots/varsommx6q/usr/lib
includedir=/home/.../build_mx6q/tmp/sysroots/varsommx6q/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10
toolsdir=${exec_prefix}/bin
pluginsdir=/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10
datarootdir=${prefix}/share
datadir=${datarootdir}
girdir=${datadir}/gir-1.0
typelibdir=${libdir}/girepository-1.0
Name: GStreamer
Description: Streaming media framework
Requires: glib-2.0, gobject-2.0, gmodule-no-export-2.0, gthread-2.0, libxml-2.0
Version: 0.10.36
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgstreamer-0.10
Cflags: -I${includedir}*
```

Compilation result:

```
warning: libffi.so.6, needed by /.../usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libz.so.1, needed by /.../usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/.../usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_pointer'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `gzdirect@ZLIB_1.2.2.3'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `gzclose'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `deflate'
/home/.../usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_float'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/.../usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_void'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `gzwrite'
/home/.../usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `ffi_type_sint64'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `crc32'
/home/.../usr/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Something went wrong, but I don't understand what and where.
I still need a help.
Thank you.

Comment: The warnings say you also need libffi and libz. Do you have all the dependencies in place?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I added libffi to Requires in gstreamer-0.10.pc, & -lz to command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc video_1.c -o basic-tutorial-1  ` pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`